# Обработка файлов с moskva.fm

Tags: аудио

Есть небезызвестный сайт moskva.fm, хранящий записи эфиров радиостанций в виде файлов-кусочков. Каждый файл — это aaс в mp4-контейнере длительностью звучания минута и две секунды. Последние две секунды совпадают с двумя первыми в следующем файле. Такое наложение используется в их плеере, но если качать из архива себе, оно неудобно и хочется избавиться.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то автоматизировать отрезание последних двух секунды из большого количества аудиофайлов без рекомпрессии? Последняя оговорка важна, т.к. качество и так не ахти, а если ещё конвертировать туда-сюда получится вообще хрень.

Comment: по-моему, проще настроить crossfade в прлеере на 2 секунды.

Comment: ffmpeg'ом можно [соединять файлы](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files), причём, если кодек одинаковый, то без перепаковки. Но поскольку вам требуется еще и отрезать ровно 2 секунды, то распаковать всё-таки придётся, чтобы срезать ровно 2*частоту_дискретизации сэмплов.